# How to debug Fortran 90 compile error "There is no specific subroutine for the generic 'foo' at (1)"?

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to write Fortran 2003 bindings to CUFFT library using iso_c_bindings module, but I have problems with `cufftPlanMany` subroutine (similar to `sfftw_plan_many_dft` in FFTW library).

The bindings itself look like this:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! cufftResult cufftPlanMany(cufftHandle *plan, int rank, int *n,
!                           int *inembed, int istride, int idist,
!                           int *onembed, int ostride, int odist,
!                           cufftType type, int batch)
!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

interface cufftPlanMany
subroutine cufftPlanMany(plan, rank, n, &
                         inembed, istride, idist, &
                         onembed, ostride, odist, &
                         type, batch) &
& bind(C,name='cufftPlanMany')
use iso_c_binding
integer(c_int):: plan
integer(c_int),value:: rank, type, batch
integer(c_int):: n(*)
integer(c_int),value:: istride, idist, ostride, odist
integer(c_int):: inembed(*), onembed(*)
end subroutine cufftPlanMany
end interface cufftPlanMany
```

The calling part looks like this:

```
  integer(c_int):: plan
  integer(c_int):: batch
  integer(c_size_t):: size

! ...

    call cufftPlanMany(plan, 1, size,&
                       0, 1, size,&
                       0, 1, size,&
                       CUFFT_C2C, batch)
```

Unfortunately trying to compile this results in

> Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic 'cufftplanmany' at (1)

compilation error.  Trying to use variables in place of constants didn't help either.  Could you help with debugging this?

The compiler used is *gfortran*: GNU Fortran (Gentoo 4.4.5 p1.2, pie-0.4.5) 4.4.5

Comment: I have accepted the more generic answer that helps debugging whole class of errors (giving better error messages), even if the error in question was what @Vladimir F noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try giving the interface and the subroutine different names, i.e., rename the interface.

Comment: I have no problems with *other* subroutines where interface has the same name as C function; it is only this one that I have problems with... unless you meant that it can help with debugging.

Comment: Thanks a lot - with interface and subroutine named differently the error messages were much more helpful, e.g. *"Error: Rank mismatch in argument 'n' at (1) (1 and 0)"*.  Fixed, now it works.

Comment: But why it didnt work in this case and did work in the others is exactly the reason from my answer, i. e. "dummy arguments do not conform to the actual arguments in your call", that's why the compiler tried to find some other subroutine in the interface which would conform and it didn't find any.

Comment: Even better than renaming the interface would be to not name it at all. Instead of simply declaring an interface for an external function (which is all that is needed here), a generic interface was created. The compiler tries to match `call cufftPlanMany(...)` (a call to a generic procedure) to one of the specific interfaces (there is only one). It can't find a match (because of non-corresponding TKR), and reports this error.

Comment: Exactly, this is the best explanation for the original error message.

Answer (score 8):

You have a generic (named) interface.

The error message normally means that some of your arguments are wrong.

In general, when you know which specific procedure of the generic interface you want to call, try to call it directly, not through the generic name. You will get another error message that will tell you, which argument is wrong. For that, you need to have the generic name and the specific name distinct.

---

Your specific case:

Why do you declare `n, inembed, onembed` as arrays, when they should be `int*`, eg. just passed as `integer` from Fortran? Also, you should not interchange `int` and `size_t`. `size_t` is commonly 64-bit and `int` 32-bit but they are simply not the same in general and should be distinguished.

Comment: They are arrays of rank `rank`, which denotes dimension.  For 1d transforms in C one would usually just pass reference to variable instead of creating an array.

Comment: @Jakub: If you declare them as arrays in the interface, you have to pass arrays in the actual procedure reference. More general, TKR (type, kind, and rank) of an actual argument have to match with that of the corresponding dummy argument.

Comment: @eriktous: I see, so C tricks (using array, or reference to scalar, or NULL) won't work in Fortran...

Comment: @Jakub: Although I'm not entirely sure I fully understand what you mean by those tricks, I think it's safe to answer the question with "no". Actual and dummy arguments simply have to match in type, kind, and rank. Basically, within Fortran, let go of the concepts of 'passing by value, or reference', just give the compiler what it wants: if it wants a scalar, give it one; if it wants an array, give it one (of the correct rank).