# Fortran 4.7.2/4.8.1 error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic 'vode' at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I try to compile the fortran program which my advisor gave me.

It doesn't want to compile when I'm doing this with gfortran 4.7.2 on Mac OS X 10.8.4 and with gfortran 4.8.1 on Arch Linux x64.

I've built the minimal working example which replays the error. Unfortunately, it's quite big anyway, so I've put it on the github: https://github.com/kabanovdmitry/vode-test

I can compile this code under Ubuntu 12.04 with gfortran 4.6.3.

I've checked press releases for GCC 4.7 and found nothing that could give me a clue.

Could you please shed some light why gfortran doesn't want to compile this code?

Sorry, initially forgot to put the errors here:

```
main.f90:8.75:

    call vode(istate, lambda_fcn, dummy_jac, lambda, x_tmp, x_end, tol, pm)
                                                                       1
Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic 'vode' at (1)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of the error message? The file/line number would be great.

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting?

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044568/how-to-debug-fortran-90-compile-error-there-is-no-specific-subroutine-for-the-g

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is covered by my answer and its comments in the question referenced by george. The type, kind and rank of arguments match exactly. To add something new, I suggest you to try to call the specific procedure directly. The type checker will then complaint for bad actual arguments and you will see more details.

In your case

```
generic2.f90:81.24:

call d_vode(istate, lambda_fcn, dummy_jac, lambda, x_tmp, x_end, tol, pm)
                    1
Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure 'f' at (1): Shape mismatch in dimension 1 of argument 'y'
```

Which is rather self-explaining. You dummy procedures are not compatible with your interfaces. You are mixing assumed-size and constant-size and explicit size arrays. You must follow the interface exactly.