# Make cannot find Fortran subroutine

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to compile some code (ifort 15.0.1), that I didn't write, using a simple Makefile. The code is F90 and mostly in module form. I've included a link to the Makefile and the two other modules in question. The code : cosp.F90 is trying to call cosp_check_input, which is inside the module cosp_utils.F90 and defined inside an interface:

```
INTERFACE COSP_CHECK_INPUT
   MODULE PROCEDURE
   COSP_CHECK_INPUT_1D,COSP_CHECK_INPUT_2D,COSP_CHECK_INPUT_3D
END INTERFACE
```

This Makefile has worked some months ago so I'm a bit baffled as to what is going wrong now. cosp.F90 is compiled both with cosp_utils.F90 (cosp.o : cosp_kinds.o cosp_simulator.o cosp_types.o cosp_modis_simulator.o cosp_utils.o) and without (cosp.o : cosp_kinds.o cosp_simulator.o cosp_types.o cosp_modis_simulator.o); but both ways result in the same error:

error #6285: There is no matching specific subroutine for this generic subroutine call.

[Files (minimal)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8fd3jmr1sbnare/Archive.zip?dl=0)

I would greatly appreciate some insights and thoughts as to what is the problem and possible solutions.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran]. This is not a Makefile problem, but a code problem, please show the code as [mcve].

Comment: Did you try googling the error message? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044568/how-to-debug-fortran-90-compile-error-there-is-no-specific-subroutine-for-the-g  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304246/fortran-4-7-2-4-8-1-error-there-is-no-specific-subroutine-for-the-generic-vode  j

Comment: I did a google search late last night. I didn't see the example you pasted. So I guess it would be simpler to remove the interface and call the subroutines directly?

Comment: Yes, do it, but for debugging. You will see the reason for the error. Then fix it and you can return to the generic.

Comment: error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [MIN_VAL]  call cosp_check_input1d('longitude',gbx%longitude,min_val=0.0_wp,max_val=360.0_wp)

I'm done that but keep getting this interface issue. This is strange because the subroutines are inside a module with a .F90 name. The keywords are optional. I don't understand this keyword issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Show the code..

Comment: I simply removed the keywords and the code compiled without error.
Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Show the code anyway or the question is really not useful here.

Comment: Here's a link to the 2 files (modules) in question: https://www.dropbox.com/s/57tvaihoh2rawc0/Archive.zip?dl=0

Comment: Code must be **in the question itself** as text. Your dropbox link can become dead at any time. And many people won't really bother downloading something. I didn't.

Comment: These are large pieces of code each over 500 lines each. It is prudent to paste such large file in the text?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302329/do-i-still-need-to-provide-code-sample-even-if-i-am-providing-fiddle-link Sure it can be made shorter. Question asking to explain a code problem without a code **in the question itself** can be closed as off-topic.

Comment: If I understand the problem from your description (haven't see the code) this reading http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/OOF90/bugs.html#10 will help you understand the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the text on generic names for a subroutine. It helped me to better understand the problem and solve it.