# There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_scatterv’ at (1)

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My system is Ubuntu Bash shell on Windows.

I use gfortran GNU Fortran (*Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5*) 5.4.0 20160609
and gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (*Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5*).
and OpenMPI to compile a file.

The flag is:

> mpifort -ffree-form -g -fbacktrace -UREPSOILM -UNLDAS2 -c test-mpi.f90

```
PROGRAM test

USE MPI

IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, DIMENSION(2)  :: xcug2m
INTEGER             :: NODID,  NUMPROCS, IERROR, COMM, DISPLS
REAL, DIMENSION(1)  :: cug2m
INTEGER             :: NPROCS=2, root
INTEGER             :: SENDCOUNTS=1
INTEGER             :: i

CALL MPI_INIT(IERROR)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(COMM, NODID,    IERROR)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(COMM, NUMPROCS, IERROR)

xcug2m = (/1,2/)

do i = 1,2
CALL MPI_SCATTERV(xcug2m(i), SENDCOUNTS, DISPLS, MPI_REAL,  &
                  cug2m,    SENDCOUNTS, MPI_REAL, root, COMM, IERROR)
end do



END PROGRAM test
```

The error is:

```
CALL MPI_SCATTERV(xc(:,i,j  ), SCOUNT, DISPLS, MPI_REAL, c(:,i  ),

       SCOUNT, MPI_REAL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, IER)
                                               1                                                                                   

Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_scatterv’ at (1).
```

I have read MPI_scatterv 's manual but found nothing. The syntax is OK. I used to compile in server with ifort and OpenMPI. There is no error and runs good.

Could you help me to solve this problem? I searched for several days.

Comment: Welcome. Use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions and tag [tag:mpi] for MPI questions. Tags are very important so that the rigjt experts see your question!. We have to see your code. Please read [mcve], [ask] and take the welcome [tour].

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044568/how-to-debug-fortran-90-compile-error-there-is-no-specific-subroutine-for-the-g we have to see your code. Not just the `call scatterv()` but a complete compilable example, where we see all types of all variables and which we can compile and test the error. The datatypes of all variables are really necessary.

Comment: Almost certainly the syntax is not ok. The error means one or more of the arguments don't match any valid call to the MPI_SCATTERV.

Comment: this suggests a typo. the second argument should be `SCOUNTS` instead of `SCOUNT`. Fortran likely complains because a scalar is used when an array is expected.

Comment: And also suggests Implicit None is not in scope, which, if the case, means I have little sympathy

Comment: At least something, but now the error message does not correspond to the code.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your reply. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated by Gilles Gouaillardet in the comments, there are several arguments, which should be arrays, but you pass scalars there.

You claimed you checked the OpenMPI manual. When I open it I see

```
MPI_SCATTERV(SENDBUF, SENDCOUNTS, DISPLS, SENDTYPE, RECVBUF,
                 RECVCOUNT, RECVTYPE, ROOT, COMM, IERROR)
            <type>    SENDBUF(*), RECVBUF(*)
            INTEGER   SENDCOUNTS(*), DISPLS(*), SENDTYPE
            INTEGER   RECVCOUNT, RECVTYPE, ROOT, COMM, IERROR
```

As you can see `SENDCOUNTS` and `DISPLS` are arrays. They indicate

```
sendcounts
                 Integer array (of length group size) specifying the number of elements to send to each processor.

       displs    Integer array (of length group size). Entry i specifies the displacement (relative to sendbuf) from which to take the outgoing data to process i.
```

They must be arrays, otherwise the program is incorrect.

The program crashes on my computer. I will not search why, it is not worth it. It may be because the value of `root` is undefined. The above-mentioned errors must be fixed.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I use mpich, then compile succeed. There maybe some compiler use different type of argument.

Comment: I repeat again: Your code is **wrong**. Even if it compiles, it is wrong. A lot of wrong code does compile.

Comment: also, you cannot `MPI_Scatterv()` in a do loop like this. the send buffer should have 2 elements, and there will be a buffer overflow when the send buffer is `xcug2m(i)`. As pointed by @Vladimir F, your code is still wrong (at least 4 errors), and it is surprising mpich is using a loose compiler (option ?) that is fooling you.