# There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘fminsearch’

Tags: optimization, fortran, overloading

I have written the following program in fortran90:

```
module constants


   real*8, parameter :: zero = 0.0d0
   real*8, parameter :: one = 1.0d0
   real*8, parameter :: two = 2.0d0

end module constants

module common

   use constants
   real*8 :: a_A, a_B, e_A, e_B, b_A, b_B

end module common   

module procedures

   use constants

   contains

   function f(p)

      use common

      real*8, dimension(2), intent(in) :: p
      real*8, dimension(2) :: f

      f(1) = a_A*((two*p(1)/p(1) + p(2))**(-e_A)) - (exp(b_A*p(1)) - one)
      f(2) = a_B*((two*p(2)/p(1) + p(2))**(-e_B)) - (exp(b_B*p(2)) - one)

      f = f

      return

   end function f

   subroutine wait

      write(6,"('Waiting...')")
      read *

      return

   end subroutine wait

end module procedures

program main 

   use constants
   use common
   use procedures
   use toolbox

   real*8, dimension(2) :: plow,phigh,pmin   

   a_A = one
   a_B = one
   e_A = one
   e_B = one
   b_A = 0.1d0
   b_b = 0.1d0


   plow(1) = 6.0d0
   plow(2) = 6.0d0

   phigh(1) = 8.0d0
   phigh(2) = 8.0d0

   pmin = one

   call fminsearch(pmin,fret,plow,phigh,f)

   write(6,"(3f15.8)") pmin(1),pmin(2), fret

end program main
```

When I run it I get the following error

```
call fminsearch(pmin, fret, plow, phigh, f)
                                     1
Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘fminsearch’ at (1)
```

I think it is a problem with my function arguments, but could anybody give me some clarity as to what is going wrong? I am new to fortran and do not quite understand. As far as I can tell, I have declared the x with intent(in) and have declared the vector output of the function.

Thank you

Comment: There's not nearly enough here for us to answer your question save to say you have almost certainly made a mistake in your argument list. To see more we will have to see at the very least what the interface for fminsearch is and the declaration of all entities used in the argument list, but much, MUCH better is a short, complete program showing the problem

Comment: And BTW it is spelt Fortran (lower case) and has been for over 25 years, and real*8 is not part of the language and has never been.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We need more code from you, a [mcve]. As Ian Bush said, you likely made an  error in your function arguments, see for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044568/how-to-debug-fortran-90-compile-error-there-is-no-specific-subroutine-for-the-g

Comment: @IanBush thanks for your response. I am new to fortran.

Comment: @VladimirF apologies for the duplicate question