# No specific subroutine for omp_set_num_threads( )

Tags: fortran, openmp

I want to set my thread number to 10, by doing:

```js
CALL OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(10)
!$OMP PARALLEL 
T=OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS()
!$OMP END PARALLEL
PRINT*, T
```

It prints out 10, which is correct. However, if I define a variable NUM_THREADS, and pass it into the get threads number subroutine, like this:

```
INTEGER(KIND=16), PARAMETER :: NUM_THREADS=10
CALL OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(NUM_THREADS)
```

And run it, it gives me the bug:

```
Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘omp_set_num_threads’ at (1).
```

Why is that?

Comment: Please give the whole program for the non-working part. `OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS` is a subroutine, so you'd need to `CALL` it. But that error would have given a different error message.

Comment: I add CALL, it still gives me the same bug. I comment out all other part, just to test the omp_set_num_threads()

Comment: Can you take out the `(KIND=16)` from the `INTEGER` declaration?

Comment: @chw21 You are right! If I cancel out the kind=16, it works. Thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4 and questions with the same error as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044568/how-to-debug-fortran-90-compile-error-there-is-no-specific-subroutine-for-the-g

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which type of integer your compiler has as `KIND=16` but it seems that it's a non-standard type for which OpenMP does not have a corresponding subroutine.

There is really no reason to use a non-standard internet kind for a number that can easily be represented by standard 16 or 32 bit integers.

Leave the kind descriptor out of the `INTEGER` declaration, and it should work.

Comment: Also note you compiler is not required to support an Integer with kind 16. If you want to use non-default interger kinds look at Select_Int_kind, or if using a compiler that supports the relevant part of Fortran 2008, the constants in the intrinsic module iso_fortran_env.