# Error: Generic function ‘send_data’ at (1) is not consistent with a specific intrinsic interface

Tags: generics, fortran

Getting the error as seen in the Title.  It is Fortran 90 code.  This is the call that throws the error:

```
if (DiagID > 0)  used = send_data(DiagID, diagField, Time)
```

This is the INTERFACE code that is called:

```
INTERFACE send_data
     MODULE PROCEDURE send_data_0d
     MODULE PROCEDURE send_data_1d
     MODULE PROCEDURE send_data_2d
     MODULE PROCEDURE send_data_3d 
#ifdef OVERLOAD_R8
     MODULE PROCEDURE send_data_0d_r8
     MODULE PROCEDURE send_data_1d_r8
     MODULE PROCEDURE send_data_2d_r8
     MODULE PROCEDURE send_data_3d_r8
#endif
  END INTERFACE
```

One of the functions referenced in the INTERFACE, is defined later as:

```
LOGICAL FUNCTION send_data_0d(diag_field_id, field, time, err_msg)
    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: diag_field_id
    REAL, INTENT(in) :: field
    TYPE(time_type), INTENT(in), OPTIONAL :: time
    CHARACTER(len=*), INTENT(out), OPTIONAL :: err_msg
     
    REAL :: field_out(1, 1, 1)
     
    ! If diag_field_id is < 0 it means that this field is not registered, simply return
    IF ( diag_field_id <= 0 ) THEN
       send_data_0d = .FALSE.
       RETURN
    END IF
    ! First copy the data to a three d array with last element 1
    field_out(1, 1, 1) = field
    send_data_0d = send_data_3d(diag_field_id, field_out, time, err_msg=err_msg)
END FUNCTION send_data_0d
```

I have limited F90 experience (spend most of my time in C/C++/Java) and am not familiar with the INTERFACE concept. Please let me know what this error means and how I can fix it. "gfortran -v" shows:

```
gcc version 14.0.1
```

Comment: Please show a [mre]. We do not see the types of the actual arguments and we do not know the combination of dummy arguments in the individual specific procedures referenced in the interface blocks. We need to know how all those entities are declared.

Comment: This usage of `Interface` works like function overloading in C-heritage languages.  The main difference is that you might still refer to the individual overloads by their specific names, which isn't a concept that exists in the C family.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044568/how-to-debug-fortran-90-compile-error-there-is-no-specific-subroutine-for-the-g and the comments under the answers for a generic explanation.